# Python Altair, pin text to bottom-right of chart

Tags: python, altair

How do I pin a piece of text, for example with `mark_text()`, to the bottom-right of the chart, so that it stays at the bottom-right corner of the chart, even when the chart is resized with, say, `.properties()`? I know I can do the following:

```py
chart = altair.Chart().mark_text(text="WTF!?!?", align="right", baseline="bottom").properties(width=300, height=100)
chart = chart.encode(x=altair.value(chart.width), y=altair.value(chart.height))
```

But with the above, the text doesn't *stay* at the bottom-right corner, for example if I do `chart.properties(width=500, height=500)`. Is there a way of doing this that is robust to resizing?

The reason I want to do this is that I have one piece of code that plots a bunch of charts, and another separate function that decides the size and layouts of the charts based on how many there are and what available space there is on the screen. There are pieces of text in each chart that need to stay at the bottom-right corner of the chart, whatever resizing is applied to the chart.

Comment: I have tried running your code and changing various graph sizes, but they all appear in the lower right corner. I ran it on altair:4.2.0.

Comment: @r-beginners I also have Altair 4.2.0. Are you sure you resized the chart *after* the `encode()`? Resize the chart to, say, a much bigger size, *after* the `encode()`.

Comment: I ran the code in the comments. The size does not change, but the text appears in the lower right corner of the first size. In the additional environment I am running on jupyterlab: 3.4.2.

Comment: @r-beginners Well the size should change. Before the size changes, the text is indeed at the lower-right corner, as it should be. Thank you for trying my code by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alt.value` anchors elements to a pixel value, whereas `alt.datum` anchors elements to a value on the scale's domain (which means it stays in place as the pixel width/height of the chart changes):

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

points = alt.Chart(pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 1], 'y': [2, 3]})).mark_point().encode(x='x', y='y')
text = chart.mark_text(text="WTF!?!?", dx=-20, dy=-5).encode(x=alt.datum(1), y=alt.datum(0))
points + text
```

[image]

```
(points + text).properties(width=700, height=50)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah yes who else but the legendary @joelostblem LOL!